# Level shifter controlled by external voltage (VL,VH)

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, control, level

I used a MOSFET to design a level shifter, but it must be adjusted according to this value by receiving an external power source.

For example, if VL = 1V and VH = 4V, the output should be between 1V and 4V

[image]

[image]

How do you design these circuits?

Comment: Could you add some more information, what does your MOSFET shifter circuit look like? A first suggestion would be to use diodes to shift the voltage level up from ground / down from VCC

Comment: My Level Shifter is below Design http://www.penguintutor.com/electronics/images/bidirect-mosfet.png    How should I use the diode? Could you explain it more?

Comment: @aAa, this level shifter is typically used with open drain IOs like I2C. They are bi-directional as well. Are you looking for a bi-directional level shifter or uni-directional? Also, are your IOs open drain? If you have these requirements, mention them in the question because then my answer will not be relevant to you

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to use an **analog mux**.

I made an analog mux using transistors for simulation purposes to illustrate the concept

VINP is your input that swings between 0-5V. The level shifted output is where I connected the voltmeter.

Following is the case where VINP=0 and the output is equal to VL=1V
[image]

Following is the case where VINP=5V and the output is equal to VH=4V
[image]

You could simplify it further and remove M2 & M3 if you are sure that the resistance of the switches M1 & M4 are good enough for the entire range of VH & VL.

You could also use an analog mux IC instead.

Comment: Thanks! Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas for you here, but there must be dozens of practical ways to do this.

You can derive an output signal that goes between 1V and 4V, derived from a 0V/5V signal using only resistors and an existing +5V source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fadkqf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I think, though that you want to be able to define the lower and upper levels using reference voltages, and you want a digital signal that switches between them based on another digital signal. With low impedance 1V and 4V voltage sources, you could do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzIhG5.png)</sup>

[image]

You'll notice it inverts.

This requires that the two sources of 1V and 4V have low impedance. You can produce a lower impedance copy of high impedance voltage sources using op-amp voltage followers. Here I use a resistor divider to create a very high impedance pair of reference 1V and 4V signals, at LW and HW (W for "weak") and then buffer them with op-amps to obtain copies LS and HS (S for "strong"), and I place the MOSFET/R1 from above between them (op-amps should be rail-to-rail output types):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fco3bE.png)</sup>

Those op-amps are not able to sink or source more than 10mA or so, so don't load them with anything that requires more than that.

Comment: Thank you Simon Fitch.
Thank you for your detailed explanation.
I understand it well because you even explained it with a simulation.